# Retry with a timer in ruby

Tags: ruby, timer

I want to do a retry operation in ruby with a small distinction: I want to do it with a timer and there might be no exceptions. The timer should measure the time all attempts have taken

Here's an example without one, but it uses "rescue" which means it assumes there'll be an exception, whereas in my code there might not be one.

```
retry_count = 5
begin
  #something
rescue
  retry_count -= 1
  if retry_count > 0
    retry
  end
end
```

My goal is just to make sure that all the attempts I make won't exceed a certain period of time.

Note that `#something` is an IO operation in can take different time in different attempts.

How can I properly  introduce  a timer here so that I won't only check the retry count but also that a certain period of time hasn't been passed yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
retry_count = 5
timeslice = 3 # sec
begin
  started = Time.now
  #something
rescue
  retry_count -= 1
  if retry_count > 0
    sleep [timeslice - (Time.now - started), 0].max
    # or, alternatively:
    # time_left = timeslice - (Time.now - started)
    # sleep timeleft if timeleft > 0
    retry
  end
end
```

Comment: I've forgotten to mention, I meant the whole time including all the attempts.

Comment: Move `started = Time.now` out of `begin` block.

Comment: haven't I seen you on youtube?

Comment: Honestly, I doubt. At least not the video I am aware of :)